# Cannot resolve reference Local ejb-ref

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, glassfish, ejb

I have an issue in programming an EJB application. I search a solution but I still have the same problem in intelliJ with Glassfish4 :
" Cannot resolve reference [Local ejb-ref name=EJB.AdminEJB,Local 3.x interface =Interface.AdminInterface,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session] because there are [2] ejbs in the application with interface Interface.AdminInterface."
And excuse-me for my english, I'm french.

**AdminInterface** in a package Interface

```
@Local
public interface AdminInterface {
public void creerParieur(Parieur parieur);

public void supprimerParieur (String login);

public void creerBookmaker(Bookmaker bookmaker);

public void supprimerBookmaker (String login);

public void modifParieur (Parieur parieur);

public void modifBookmaker (Bookmaker bookmaker);

public void ajouterCote(Cote cote);

public void ajouterMatch (Match match);

public List<Cote> listeCote(String log);

public List<Match> listeMatch();

public List<Parieur> listeParieur();

public List<Bookmaker> listeBookmaker();

public Parieur rechercheParieur(String id);

public Bookmaker rechercheBookmaker (String id);

public void setLogin(String login);

public String getLogin();
```

}

**AdminEJB** in a package EJB

```
@Stateless
public class AdminEJB implements AdminInterface{
String login;
String mdp;
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "NewPersistenceUnit")
EntityManager em;

public AdminEJB(){}

public String getLogin(){
    return login;
}

public void setLogin(String login){
    this.login=login;
}

public String getMdp(){
    return mdp;
}

public void setMdp(String mdp){
    this.mdp=mdp;
}

public void creerParieur(Parieur parieur){
    em.persist(parieur);
}

public void supprimerParieur(String login){
    Parieur parieur=new Parieur ();
    Query req=em.createQuery("select OBJECT(P) from Parieur P where P.login=:login");
    req.setParameter("login", login);
    parieur=(Parieur)req.getSingleResult();
    em.remove(parieur);
}

public void modifParieur(Parieur parieur){
    em.merge(parieur);
}

public List<Parieur> listeParieur(){
    Query req=em.createQuery("select OBJECT(P) from Parieur P");
    return req.getResultList();
}

public void creerBookmaker(Bookmaker bookmaker){
    em.persist(bookmaker);
}

public void supprimerBookmaker(String login){
    Bookmaker bookmaker;
    Query req=em.createQuery("select OBJECT(B) from Bookmaker B where B.pseudo=:login");
    req.setParameter("login", login);
    bookmaker=(Bookmaker)req.getSingleResult();
    em.remove(bookmaker);
}

public void modifBookmaker(Bookmaker bookmaker){
    em.merge(bookmaker);
}

public List<Bookmaker> listeBookmaker(){
    Query req=em.createQuery("select OBJECT(B) from Bookmaker B");
    return req.getResultList();
}

public List<Match> listeMatch(){
    Query req=em.createQuery("select OBJECT(M) from Match M");
    return req.getResultList();
}

public Bookmaker rechercheBookmaker(String id){
    return em.find(Bookmaker.class,id);
}

public Parieur rechercheParieur(String id){
    return em.find(Parieur.class,id);
}

public void ajouterCote (Cote cote){
    em.persist(cote);
}

public void ajouterMatch (Match match){
    em.persist(match);
}

public List<Cote> listeCote(String log){
    Bookmaker bookmaker = new Bookmaker();
    bookmaker = this.rechercheBookmaker(log);
    Query req = em.createQuery("select OBJECT(C) from Cote C where C.bookmaker=:bookmaker");
    req.setParameter("bookmaker", bookmaker);
    return req.getResultList();
}
```

}

**ControlerBean** in a package ManagedBean

```
   @ManagedBean
  @RequestScoped
  public class ControlerBean implements Serializable{
Bookmaker bookmaker;
Pari pari;
Parieur parieur;
Match match;
Cote cote;
String nomObjetP;
String nomEnP;
String pseudoUser;
String pwdUser;

@EJB
private AdminInterface admin;

public ControlerBean(){
    bookmaker = new Bookmaker();
    parieur = new Parieur();
    cote = new Cote();
    match= new Match();
    pari= new Pari();

}

public String getNomObjetP() {
    return nomObjetP;
}

public void setNomObjetP(String nomObjetP) {
    this.nomObjetP = nomObjetP;
}

public String getNomEnP() {
    return nomEnP;
}

public void setNomEnP(String nomEnP) {
    this.nomEnP = nomEnP;
}

public Pari getPari() {
    return pari;
}

public void setPari(Pari pari){
    this.pari=pari;
}

public Bookmaker getBookmaker() {
    return bookmaker;
}

public void setBookmaker(Bookmaker bookmaker) {
    this.bookmaker = bookmaker;
}

public Parieur getParieur() {
    return parieur;
}

public void setParieur(Parieur parieur) {
    this.parieur = parieur;
}

public Cote getCote() {
    return cote;
}

public void setCote(Cote cote) {
    this.cote = cote;
}

public Match getMatch(){
    return match;
}

public void setMatch(Match match){
    this.match=match;
}

public AdminInterface getAdmin() {
    return admin;
}

public void setAdmin(AdminInterface admin) {
    this.admin = admin;
}

public String getPseudoUser() { return pseudoUser; }

public void setPseudoUser(String pseudoUser) {
    this.pseudoUser = pseudoUser;
}

public String getPwdUser() {
    return pwdUser;
}

public void setPwdUser(String pwdUser) {
    this.pwdUser = pwdUser;
}

public String addParieur(){
    parieur.setArgent(1000);
    admin.creerParieur(parieur);
    return "OK";
}

public String modifParieur(){
    admin.modifParieur(parieur);
    return "OK";
}

public String supprParieur(){
    admin.supprimerParieur(parieur.getLogin());
    return "OK";
}

public String addBookmaker(){
    admin.creerBookmaker(bookmaker);
    return "OK";
}

public String modifBookmaker(){
    admin.modifBookmaker(bookmaker);
    return "OK";
}

public String supprBookmaker(){
    admin.supprimerBookmaker(bookmaker.getPseudo());
    return "OK";
}

public List<Bookmaker> listeBookmaker(){
    return admin.listeBookmaker();
}

public List<Parieur> listeParieur(){
    return admin.listeParieur();
}

public List<Match> listeMatch(){ return admin.listeMatch(); }

public String addCote(){
    pseudoUser = admin.getLogin();
    cote.setBookmaker(admin.rechercheBookmaker(pseudoUser));
    admin.ajouterCote(cote);
    return "OK";
}

public String addMatch(){
    admin.ajouterMatch(getMatch());
    return "OK";
}
```

}

Thank's very much for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have two EJBs implementing the same interface they need to be differentiated so that the container knows which one to inject.

Add the name parameter in the @Stateless annotation to all beans implementing the same interface. In the @EJB annotation, use the beanName parameter to inject the appropriate session bean implementation.

```
@Stateless(name="AdminEJB1") 
public class AdminEJB implements AdminInterface { .... }

@EJB(beanName = "AdminEJB1") 
private AdminInterface myAdminEjb;
```

You can also skip the name parameter in the @Stateless annotation and then use the name of the implementing class as the beanName parameter in the @EJB annotation.

```
@Stateless
public class AdminEJB implements AdminInterface { .... }

@EJB(beanName = "AdminEJB") 
private AdminInterface myAdminEjb;
```

Comment: Thank's very much that solved this problem (now I have a 404 but it's an other problem)

Comment: a tip that may be useful that can be useful: using this strategy you need to use the interface rather than the class directly. This `private AdminInterface myAdminEjb;` rather than `private AdminEJB myAdminEjb;`

Answer (score 1):

I had same error, but I didn't work with one interface for different EJBs (generated local Session Beans from entity classes). So I am putting this answer if somebody had same problem as me, as I didn't found one here. My framework generated  "ejb-local-ref" tag in pom.xml on its own. After deleting it, all works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Another cause for this problem, although uncommon, may be the delay in communicating with the JMX port. To get around this it is possible to put the key -Dhk2.parser.timeout = 300